# Blazor app being published to azure for testing has started timing out on upload

Tags: c#, azure, blazor, azure-web-app-service, devops

I am making a blazor web app in visual studio using net 8.

It is a big and busy project. But at 11am today i was able to click the publish button. Upload a large amount of changes and show them all working through the azure preview links.

I show my boss the work and nothing goes wrong at all.

Then i come back to my desk make a small change to an event listener that would hopefully not effect anything.

Now when i click the publish button the blazor app will open two admin windows to confirm auth. Then runs for about 10 minutes.
Then fails completely. It appears to be a timeout error.

All my logs indicate that i passed all my builds and tests.

Weirdly it has now started creating a zip file in my main project folder containing the entire build. I never asked it to do this. Its a zip file with a long uuid random name. Inside is wwwroot, assets, framework and so on.

Its like my app has decided to stop publishing to web and just creating the file on my local machine.

I Will include a lot of log data and error messages below. But they are a bit vague.

I was hoping someone had come across this issue before and could help me to solve it.
Im sorry i cant explain it better. There is so little to say. My errors messages suck.

Thanks, please help.

Here is my window output

```
Publish has encountered an error.
The operation has timed out.

A diagnostic log has been written to the following location:
"C:\Users\tbrockington\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpB1BC.tmp"
```

Here is that files data

```
e19/01/2024 12:10:20
System.TimeoutException: The operation has timed out.
at Microsoft.WebTools.Shared.VS.Threading.TaskExtensions. 
<WaitForCompleteOrTimeout>d__1.MoveNext()
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
 at 
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task 
task)
at Microsoft.WebTools.Shared.VS.Helpers.ProcessWrapper. 
<WaitForExitAsync>d__38.MoveNext()
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at 
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task 
task)
at Microsoft.WebTools.Azure.Publish.SWA.StaticWebAppCli.<RunAsync>d__52.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at 
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task 
task)
at Microsoft.WebTools.Azure.Publish.SWA.StaticWebAppPublisher. 
<RunStaticWebAppCliAsync>d__14.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at 
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task 
task)
at Microsoft.WebTools.Azure.Publish.SWA.StaticWebAppPublisher. 
<AuthenticateAsync>d__10.MoveNext()
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at 
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task 
task)
at Microsoft.WebTools.Azure.Publish.NewFx.Profiles.PublishSteps.SWALoginPublishStep. 
<RunAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at Microsoft.Publish.Framework.Profiles.ProjectProfilesManager. 
<RunPublishStepsAsync>d__38.MoveNext()
```

Comment: Just to clarify, are hosting the website on an Azure VM or Azure App Service WebApp?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you’re experiencing issues with publishing your Blazor app to Azure. The error message you’re seeing indicates a timeout issue. Following-up from my comment, to better assist you please share more details about your setup.

If you haven't tried already so, you may try the following steps to isolate the issue:

As outlined in [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/server?view=aspnetcore-8.0): If a deployed app frequently displays the reconnection UI due to ping timeouts caused by Internet latency, lengthen the server and client timeouts:

It is recommended to use the Azure SignalR Service for server-side Blazor apps. The service works in conjunction with the app's Blazor Hub for scaling up a server-side Blazor app to a large number of concurrent SignalR connections.

Also, it is [recommend](https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/server?view=aspnetcore-8.0#azure-signalr-service) to use WebSockets for server-side Blazor apps deployed to Azure App Service. The Azure SignalR Service uses WebSockets by default.

To narrow-down, try reducing the size of your deployment by removing unnecessary files or optimizing your assets.

For App Service, you may leverage **App Service diagnostics** from Azure Portal> Navigate to your App Service app in the Azure Portal.

In the left navigation, click on `Diagnose and solve problems` - Review - “Configuration and Management and “Availability and Performance”  options.